# Excel recognizing Booleans and making them ugly

Tags: microsoft-excel, display

If I enter this in a cell:

```
True
```

Excel automatically displays it ALL CAPS and centers it in the cell.

What’s going on with that, and how do I stop it?

I don’t think I want to do something like formatting this particular cell.  And I don't want to have to enter the text with a quote before it, like this:

```
'True
```

I just want Excel to stop messing with cells if I enter "True" or "False" in them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before entering your data, select the range and format it as "Text". Then you can type the word "true" or "false" and it will not be converted to a Boolean.

If the cell is formatted as "General", Excel will perform its interpretation of the input and converts/formats differently for text, dates, numbers, booleans.

You need to apply the Text format BEFORE you enter the data, though, because once the data type has been applied, Excel will not change it unless each cell is edited.

[image]